# Referencing externalized pgfplots with subfig and cleveref

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref, tikz-external

I use `pgfplots` to produce a vast amount of images in my document. Due to limited LaTeX memory, I am forced to use `\tikzexternalize`. Moreover, I also use the `subfig` package to group several pictures into a single float and the `cleveref` package. So far, everything works perfect. However, when I add references to my externalized images, strange bugs occur.

In short, **some plots which are based on data from files do not produce correct references. The exact same plots with fixed data do produce correct references**. Apart from that, both methods results in correct images. My only problem are the missing references.

Due to the complexity of the project, it is hard to deliver a complete working sample code which produces such a bug. I hope the following explanations are enough to give you a rough idea of what might go wrong.

For all images, I use a shortcut command. Let us assume we have

```
\newcommand{\myfigureA}[1]{\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4cm,height=4cm]
\addplot3[surf] file{#1.data};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:#1}}
```

and

```
\newcommand{\myfigureB}[1]{\tikzsetnextfilename{#1}\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4cm,height=4cm]
\addplot3[surf] coordinates {
(0,0,0) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (3,0,0)
(0,1,0) (1,1,0.6) (2,1,0.7) (3,1,0.5)
(0,2,0) (1,2,0.7) (2,2,0.8) (3,2,0.5)};
\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\label{fig:#1}}
```

When I use `\myfigureB{name}` to produce a certain image, all references `\cref{fig:name}` are working. On the other hand, when I use `\myfigureA{name}`, all references `\cref{fig:name}` are broken and I get "**??**" signs instead. However, both `\myfigureA{name}` and `\myfigureB{name}` result in *the exact same image* in the final PDF document (assuming the coordinates in the file correspond to the coordinates given here). Strangely enough, references to some images (always the same images) do in fact work. I have no idea what makes these images different from the others.

A usage of these commands to produce a series of four images might look like this:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\subfloat[][]{\myfigureA{name1}}
\subfloat[][]{\myfigureA{name2}} \\
\subfloat[][]{\myfigureA{name3}}
\subfloat[][]{\myfigureA{name4}}
\caption{caption text}
\end{figure}
```

I use the latest versions of all mentioned packages. Compilation is performed by the usual four commands, namely `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape mylatexfile`, `bibtex mybibliography`, `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape mylatexfile` and `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape mylatexfile`.

In the `.log` file of the main document I only get the "Labels may have changed..." message for both `\myfigureA{name}` and `\myfigureB{name}`, but even compiling a few dozen times does not change this. I think this might be a result of the externalization process. The individual log files of the externalized images show a lot of missing references for both `\myfigureA{name}` and `\myfigureB{name}`, although in the former case they do work in the final PDF document. In the latter case, they do not, as already mentioned. The `cleveref` package does not seem to have anything to do with this bug.

Unfortunately, I have no more ideas where else to look for my bug.

Comment: So, the key seems to be the difference between file input and inline coordinate input, right? If I am not mistaken, the only difference between external images using file and coordinate input is when `mode=list and make` is used: pgfplots writes the input file name into the makefile dependencies. I am currently unaware of other differences. Did you try other image conversion modes (like `mode=convert with system call`)? You could also try to insert `\relax` before your `\label` commands to exclude string gobbling bugs in the external lib (although not very likely)

Comment: you could also try to set `/pgf/images/aux in dpth=false` which will deactivate references/labels inside of externalized images - this will free a further write register.

Comment: "the key seems to be the difference between file input and inline coordinate input" - Yes, apparently at least. Thanks for these hints, trying them out.

Comment: If it does not help, it might be interesting to study the `.aux` files (and perhaps the `.dpth` files as well). They should contain the definitions of the `\label` commands in question.

Comment: Interestingly, all `.dpth` files are empty! There also seem to exist no `.aux` files for my individual externalized pictures. Do I have to enable these somewhere?

Comment: The `.dpth` files can be empty - they contain everything that is usually written to `.aux` files + information for the `baseline` feature. They have to be non-empty in case you have labels inside of the external pictures. In all other cases, the remaining `.aux` files should contain your references in some form.

Comment: Good hint! I actually _have_ labels in my external pictures, but empty `.dpth` files! Is there any specific place to search for the reason of this behavior? Besides, only my `.tex` documents have associated `.aux` files, not the externalized images.

Comment: The main reference should be the pgfmanual (or perhaps the pgfplots manual http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf which contains at least extracts for the external lib). I suggest we move the further problem-finding discussion to a mail conversation (see the pgfplots.pdf link above for my mail address).

Comment: Thank you! I will resume searching in your reference and maybe accept your kind offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like I oversaw a deep-seated conflict between `auto-pst-pdf` and `externalize`. Disabling the former makes all my references available.

As an alternative, I can also use `externalize` and `auto-pst-pdf` with the `[runs=1]` option. An option `[runs=2]` or higher may lead to missing references though.