# TikZ Externalize: Referenced legends from PGFPlots are not included

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

The following MWE without `TikZ` externalization works. However, the legend at the bottom is lost with externalization. Since the `\ref` in this example does not refer to anything outside `tikzpicture` environment, I thought this should work. However, I understand that `latex` needs to loop twice to resolve the reference and is not able to do it here.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[%
      legend entries={$\sin(x)$},
      legend to name = named,
      name = plt 
    ]   
    \addplot {sin(deg(x))}; 
  \end{axis}
  \node[at=(plt.south),anchor=north] {\ref{named}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I move `\ref{named}` outside the `tikzpicture` environment, I can generate two separate PDF files using `list and make` mode. However, I would like to keep the legends with my plot.

PS: MWE is only representative. This will be used for legend entries with multiple subplots.

Comment: Did you try exhausting all the options stated in the manual? There is a whole section about how and why specifically adressing cross references..

Comment: Could you add answer with `\pgfplotslegendfromname{name}` instead of `\ref{name}`? I figured it out, but didn't know how to let people know.

Comment: Just wait a little bit(!) and the system will allow you to answer your own question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the solution. `\ref` is not really required in this case. If `\ref{named}` is substituted with `\pgfplotslegendfromname{named}` then the MWE works. Though `\ref` can be used to put the legend, it is not a good usage.

Comment: The failure of `\ref` sounds more like a bug to me... but good to know that there is a working solution. perhaps the externalization has to be run twice just a other latex documents?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish practically the same thing, only within a groupplot.  Though the manual says that the groupplot environment should function basically the same as the axis environment, it doesn't seem to with regard to names.  So where you used `name=plt` so that you could later use `\node[at=(plt.south)` I can't seem to replicate for a groupplot.  No matter what I try, I get the error No shape named plt is known.