# Tikzexternal and References

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, tikz-external

I understand that `tikzexternal` has difficulty when graphics objects contain references (cite, ref, etc...), due to issues with getting lock on the aux file: [References in externalized pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/references-in-externalized-pgfplots)

However, in my case, I am ONLY interested in externalizing the objects during draft runs, when the draft option is specified. At such time, the references are not important, only during the final run.

How can I use tikzexternal in manner such that when the document is in draft, all the embedded references simply get ignored, therefore avoiding the aux file lock conflict.

During the final run, I switch of tikzextrnal **entirely** via the `\tikzexternaldisable` command, so that the final graphics is rendered with the appropriate references.

Comment: according to the accepted answer there, the solution is just as usual you need to run latex again to resolve the references, so for draft runs there is no issue, it will sort itself out automatically. Do you have a MWE that shows a problem?

Comment: Nicholas, did David's suggestions resolve the problem?