# Citation in externalized pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, cross-referencing, citing

I have a few `\cite` commands in my `pgfplots` which are not being displayed properly when `externalization` in on. As soon as you turn off the `externalization`, the references will be displayed correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=-1,xmax=1,xlabel = \cite{Lorem}, title=\cite{Lorem2}, ylabel=\cite{Lorem3}]
\addplot 
coordinates{ (0,0)(2,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{thebibliography}{99\kern\bibindent}

\bibitem{Lorem}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\bibitem{Lorem2}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}

\bibitem{Lorem3}\textsc{Lorem ipsum dolor sit}
\texttt{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vitae purus mi. Fusce quam urna, elementum at ullamcorper in, tempus sed quam.}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is likely to do with the way you compile your document, please see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/references-in-externalized-pgfplots/40684#40684 and if that helps you

Comment: This is also mentioned in the manual about ref/label mechanism.