# How to reference an equation number within TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm attempting to dynamically reference an Equation number in `tikzpicture` (via `\eqref` or `\ref`) using the following:

```
% Filename:  Test.tex (say)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% Due to a large number of Tikz plots
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
Here is an equation:
\begin{equation}
    \label{eqOne}
    y = x^2
\end{equation}
that I'd like to appear in TikZ.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids
]

\addplot[const plot,color=red,solid,line width=0.5pt] plot table[row sep=crcr] {%
0  0\\
1  1\\
2  4\\
3  9\\
};
]
\node[right, align=left, inner sep=0mm] at (axis cs:2,4) {Equation \eqref{eqOne}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but this won't work via `pdflatex -shell-escape Test.tex`.  The output generated shows 'Equation (??)'

By trial and error, dynamic referencing seems to only work without `\usepgfplotslibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize`, but I need these two lines due to the number of TikZ plots that I have.

Is there a way around this dynamic referencing problem; perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Many thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Did you try running `pdflatex` twice?

Comment: Please minimize your code as much as possible and describe your compilation routine. As Peter mentioned, pdfLaTeX has to be invoked twice. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: Looks like this is more than the usual "just run it twice" issue. Does [References in externalized pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/references-in-externalized-pgfplots) answer your question. If so, we'll close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use \theequation until the next equation, or use \global\edef\eqOne{\theequation} to store the number.

Comment: Many thanks for everyone's great feedback and help!  Peter's link to [references in externalized pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/references-in-externalized-pgfplots) solved this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Peter's link to [references in externalized pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40652/references-in-externalized-pgfplots) solved my problem!

Just to be explicit for others:  for this example (using file Test.tex), the figure # in question (starting from 0) is 0 (here, there's only one figure); so:

`pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Test-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Test}\input{Test}"`

followed by

`pdflatex -shell-escape Test.tex`

worked!

My sincere thanks to Peter and this forum/group!!